# Get exact looking direction to launch player

Tags: java, bukkit

I am making a plugin to throw a player towards his cursor (The crosshair).
I already made it work using `player.getLocation().getYaw()`, but for some reason the yaw is sometimes negative.

What I tried to do is

```
player.setVelocity(new Vector(2.0f, 1.3f, Math.cos(player.getLocation().getYaw() * 180 / Math.PI)));
```

It works only 50% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also simply use `player.setVelocity(player.getLocation().getDirection())` to throw the player towards their crosshair/the direction they are facing. You can manipulate the direction vector in all sorts of ways to change the jump behavior, for example by multiplying the vector by a constant to increase/decrease the force of the jump/push.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)
But I think my way is more percise

Comment: I'd highly suggest you first try this method and see if it works for you. It requiring one line of code doesn't in any way make it less precise. The x, y, and z components of the direction vector are updated just as often and are just as accurate as the yaw and pitch values of the player location (despite them being numerically smaller values). The trig calculations you're doing to get the correct values are already calculated for you with the direction vector.

Comment: I used my method to individually set the Y strength and X/Z strength, I did not want them to be equal or affected by and multiplication.

Comment: Yes, you can do this very easily with the direction `Vector` object as well. For example if you want the player to be thrown more vertically than horizontally you can change the Y value of the vector with `direction.setY(direction.getY() * 2)`. The x, y and z values are almost never equal (not quite sure what you mean by this), they represent the components of a normalized vector facing the direction of the player. Changing the proportion between the x and z values however will result in the player not being pushed towards the crosshair, which is what I believe you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative that works is to subtract the coorinates of the player, from those of the target block (or the other way round). There are better ways to do it, but ir never hurts to try more than one way!
Here is a quick example of how it might be written:

```
victim.setVelocity(new Vector((epicenter.getLocation().getX() - victim.getLocation().getX())/4,(epicenter.getLocation().getY() - victim.getLocation().getY())/4,(epicenter.getLocation().getZ() - victim.getLocation().getZ())/4));
```

(In the example, victim is the player and epicenter is the target block from p.getTargetBlock())